# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str' | pandas reindex

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, reindex

Im getting a lengthy error traceback with last line as stated in title.

Im trying to use `nearest` method to fill the missing values during reindexing.

Heres my code:

```
import pandas as pd
s1=pd.Series([1,2,3,4],index=list('aceg'))
print(s1.reindex(pd.Index(list('abdg')),method='nearest'))
```

I was trying to see if filling missing info is done after reindexing or during reindexing which might affect the result in this case of `method = 'nearest'`.
Changing the `method` to `ffill` or `bfill` works fine.

Comment: As the error message says you can't reindex using strings and nearest. You must replace strings with numbers.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do that with strings because the distance between two strings doesn't mean much. For this use case, you can convert your one-character index as a number with the `ord` function:

```
s1 = pd.Series([1,2,3,4], index=list('aceg'))
idx = pd.Index(list('gdba'))

s1.index = idx[s1.index.map(ord).reindex(idx.map(ord), method='nearest')[1]]
print(s1)

# Output:
a    1
b    2
d    3
g    4
dtype: int64
```

Details:

```
>>> s1.index.map(ord)
Int64Index([97, 98, 100, 103], dtype='int64')

>>> idx.map(ord)
Int64Index([103, 100, 98, 97], dtype='int64')
```

If you have strings index instead of one-character index, you can handle it with fuzzy logic and [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)

Comment: Isn't it a bit weird since normal user like me would expect it to work as the missing values can try to see nearby values and pick the nearest one. Why need a specific type of index when index shouldn't matter here, cuz order of current data can tell which valid value is nearest

Comment: It is easy to calculate a distance between dates / numbers and find the closest value but understand that it is not easy for strings. You have two strings: 'hello' and 'bye': which is the closest to 'hello'? 'bye' seems to be the closest although 'hello' while 'bonjour' means 'hello' in French.

Comment: So it tries to see valued difference instead of spatial distance in the dataframe?